# How to replace width and height form a string like 'imagename-300x200.ext'

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Using javascript I'm updating the `src` of the images changing the width and height that the `url` accepts, so it's the closest (in 100px steps) one to the user size based on his viewport size

And [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3v6vx24n/5/) code works:

```
var choose_image_res = function( $img ) {
  var width = $img.width(); // Ancho real
  var height = $img.height(); // Alto real
  var src = $img.attr('src'); // looks like http://domain.com/uploads/image-name-300x200.jpg'
  var part = src.split('/');
  var resolution = part[part.length-1].split('.')[0].split('-')[1]; // Better with regex, right? 
  var resto = width % 100;
  if ( resto >= 50 ) {
    var newWidth = Math.round(width + (100-resto));  // Ancho más próximo a múltiplo de 100
  } else {
    var newWidth = Math.round(width - resto);    
  }
  var newHeight = Math.round(height*newWidth / width); // Alto proporcional al nuevo ancho
  $img.attr('src', src.replace(resolution, newWidth+'x'+newHeight )  ) ; // Implementamos dimensiones
}
```

but i'm sure that the `.replace` part could use a regex and that it will be faster, the thing is that don't a have a clue how it should look,

can anyone show me the light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another - safer - regex can be used here:

```
src.replace(/\d+x\d+(?=[^.\/]*\.[^.\/]+$)/, newWidth+'x'+newHeight )
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bJ6sU6/2)

Even if you have `http://domain.com/uploads300x200/image-name-300x200.jpg` the regex will replace the **last** `digits`+x+`digits` sequence due to the positive lookahead that requires this sequence to be followed by

- `(?=`

  - `[^.\/]*` - zero or more characters other than `.` and `/` (allow any more characters after the resolution)
  - `\.` - a literal dot
  - `[^.\/]+` - 1 or more  characters other than `.` and `/` (aka extension, perhaps, even safer is to use `\w+` here)
  - `$` - end of string
- `)`.

Answer (score 2):

let's say your image src is in `image` and your new dimension string is `dim` . 
Then you can do it like this:

```
image.replace(/\d+x\d+/, dim)
```

Comment: What would happen if the image has `x` in the name?

Comment: doesn't matter, it will only replace [digits]x[digits], which is very unlikely to be in image src..

Comment: Works great, and I like the simplicity of it! thanks!

Comment: "Simple" word is not always best regex friend. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yB3cN9/1) if there is a `digits`+`x`+`digits` sequence in the middle of the string.

Comment: in that case you might want to try this `/\d+x\d+/g`. It will replace both such strings..

Answer (score 1):

> based on his viewport size

Unless you're using CSS which you haven't shared, the size of the view port is independent to the size of an `<img>`

```
function viewPortSize() {
    var o = {}, d = document;
    o.x = window.innerWidth || d.documentElement.clientWidth || d.body.clientWidth;
    o.y = window.innerHeight|| d.documentElement.clientHeight|| d.body.clientHeight;
    if (!o.x && o.x !== 0) o.x = -1;
    if (!o.y && o.y !== 0) o.y = -1;
    return o;
}
```

So,

```
var choose_image_res = function( $img ) {
    var src = $img.attr('src'); // looks like http://.../image-name-300x200.jpg'
    src = src.replace(/-\d+\d+\.([^./]+)$/, function ($0, $1) {
        var o = viewPortSize();
        o.x = o.x - (o.x % 100);
        o.y = o.y - (o.y % 100);
        return '-' + o.x + 'x' + o.y + '.' + $1;
    });
    $img.attr('src', src); // Implementamos dimensiones
}
```

---

> the images have `width:100%`

The method you're looking for is [`Element.prototype.getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), here is a function which returns output in the same style as the `viewPortSize` function above did

```
function imageSize(img) {
    var o = {}, rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    o.x = rect.width;
    o.y = rect.height;
    return o;
}
```

You would now call this on the *Element* (not the *jQuery Object*) to get it's dimensions

```
// ...
        var o = imageSize($img[0]);
// ...
```

Comment: Sorry, the images have `width:100%` so the viewport size it's not relevant for this code; but it determinates the image's width. but i think that the `replace` code of your answer helps me :) (I added a jsfiddle)